# MATLAB Array of structures assignment

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I have an array of structures. Lets say 
    `s(1).value`, ... , `s(5).value`.
I have a vector of values, lets say `vals = [1 2 3 4 5]`, that i want to assign to the array of structures. So written in pseudocode i want: `s(:).value = vals`.

As shown below there is a know solution. But is it really not possible to do this assignment in 1 line as in the pseudocode?

```
% Vector of values
vals = [1 2 3 4 5];
n = length(vals);

% Initialize struct
s(n).values = 0;

% Put vals into my struct.values
[s(1:n).values] = ???

% Known solution that i am not satisfied with:
vals_c = num2cell(vals);
[s(1:n).values] = vals_c{:};
```

Best regards, Jonas

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the method you mentioned? Looks quite neat to me.

Comment: Because for each vector of values i put into the struct (such as vals) i need to have a line with "vals_c = num2cell(vals);"

Comment: The solution you have is probably best. my approach would require struct merging, which would probably end up being messier than this solution

Answer (score 1):

Having recently gone through the same phase I thought I'd answer this one.

To create a new structure with one field:

```
field = 'f';
value = {'some text';
         [10, 20, 30];
         magic(5)};
s = struct(field,value)
```

Create a nonscalar structure with several fields:

```
field1 = 'f1';  value1 = zeros(1,10);
field2 = 'f2';  value2 = {'a', 'b'};
field3 = 'f3';  value3 = {pi, pi.^2};
field4 = 'f4';  value4 = {'fourth'};

s = struct(field1,value1,field2,value2,field3,value3,field4,value4)
```

Also, as I'd always suggest, going over the documentation a few times is quite necessary and useful, so there you go. https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html

Comment: Thank you. To summarize i can solve my problem using
   
   field1 = 'values';
   vals = [1:5];
   struct(field1,num2cell(vals));

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this in one line using [cell2struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) in conjuction with num2cell.

```
% Vector of values
vals = [1 2 3 4 5];
n = length(vals);


% Put vals into my struct.values
s = cell2struct(num2cell(vals), 'values', 1)

% transpose if orientation is important
s  = s.';
```

it's not pretty, but it does do it in one line. `cell2struct` supports multiple entries so you may be able to populate many fields.

The big downside is that it creates the struct from scratch, so you'd have to do a struct merge if you need to add this data to an existing struct.

Comment: This method works only for the first field of the structure. What if `s.field1` exists and `values` is supposed to be added to `s`?

Comment: As I said, that is the downside of this approach. You'd have to create a second struct and merge them, or add them both in the same call to `cell2struct`.

Comment: Sorry, I totally didn't see the last line of your answer.

Comment: Interesting solution, but as you mention does this rely upon initializing the struct (and as does Abhinav Ralhan's solution). I think i prefer the "struct('values',num2cell(vals));" solution